# C#: Using pointer types as fields?

Tags: c#, pointers, unsafe

In C#, it's possible to declare a struct (or class) that has a pointer type member, like this:

```
unsafe struct Node
{
  public Node* NextNode;
}
```

Is it ever safe (err.. ignore for a moment that ironic little `unsafe` flag..) to use this construction? I mean for longterm storage on the heap. From what I understand, the GC is free to move things around, and while it updates the references to something that's been moved, does it update pointers too? I'm guessing no, which would make this construction very unsafe, right?

I'm sure there are way superior alternatives to doing this, but call it morbid curiosity.

EDIT: There appears to be some confusion. I know that this isn't a great construction, I *purely* want to know if this is ever a safe construction, ie: is the pointer guaranteed to keep pointing to whatever you originally pointed it to?

The original C-code was used to traverse a tree (depth first) without recursion, where the tree is stored in an array. The array is then traversed by incrementing a pointer, unless a certain condition is met, then the pointer is set to the NextNode, where traversal continues. Of course, the same can in C# be accomplished by:

```
struct Node
{
  public int NextNode;
  ... // other fields
}
```

Where the `int` is the index in the array of the next node. But for performance reasons, I'd end up fiddling with pointers and `fixed` arrays to avoid bounds checks anyway, and the original C-code seemed more natural.

Comment: The GC does not move areas of memory that have been pinned to a memory location using the fixed keyword.

Comment: why would you want to do that in the first place ?

Comment: However, `fixed` can only be used in local scope (i.e. you cannot pin something and return it from a method without unpinning it first), which kinda limits the uses.

Comment: JulianR, in my mind you haven't provided a good reason yet why you can't replace struct by class and simply use a reference...

Comment: There's no reason why I can't use a class, and I can use a reference to the next node, but that way the method of "increment the index and go one deeper into the tree" won't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is it ever safe to use this construction? I mean for long term storage on the heap.

Yes. Doing so is usually foolish, painful and unnecessary, but it is possible.

> From what I understand, the GC is free to move things around, and while it updates the references to something that's been moved, does it update pointers too?

No. **That's why we make you mark it as unsafe.**

> I'm guessing no, which would make this construction very unsafe, right?

Correct.

> I'm sure there are way superior alternatives to doing this, but call it morbid curiosity.

There certainly are.

> is the pointer guaranteed to keep pointing to whatever you originally pointed it to?

Not unless you ensure that happens. There are two ways to do that.

Way one: Tell the garbage collector to not move the memory. There are two ways to do that:

- Fix a variable in place with the "fixed" statement.
- Use interop services to create a gc handle to the structures you wish to keep alive and in one place.

**Doing either of these things will with high likelihood wreck the performance of the garbage collector.**

Way two: Don't take references to memory that the garbage collector can possibly move. There are two ways to do that:

- Only take addresses of local variables, value parameters, or stack-allocated blocks. Of course, in doing so you are then required to ensure that the pointers do not survive longer than the relevant stack frame, otherwise, you're referencing garbage.
- Allocate a block out of the unmanaged heap and then use pointers inside that block. In essence, implement your own memory manager. You are required to correctly implement your new custom memory manager. Be careful.

Comment: A complete answer, thank you :)
I think I'll opt for the much simpler "store an index integer to the next node" method, was gonna do that anyway, but yeah, morbid curiosity.

Answer (score 3):

Some obvious integrity checks have been excluded. The obvious problem with this is you have to allocate more than you will need because you cannot reallocate the buffer as the keyword **fixed** implies.

```
public unsafe class NodeList
{
    fixed Node _Nodes[1024];
    Node* _Current;

    public NodeList(params String[] data)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
        {
            _Nodes[i].Data = data[i];
            _Nodes[i].Next = (i < data.Length ? &_Nodes[i + 1] : null);     
        }

        _Current = &_Nodes[0];
    }

    public Node* Current()
    {
        return _Current++;  
    }
}

public unsafe struct Node
{
    public String Data;
    public Node* Next;
}
```

Comment: It is quite usable as long as you keep your lists smaller than 1024.

Answer (score 2):

Why not:

```
struct Node
{
    public Node NextNode;
}
```

or at least:

```
struct Node
{
    public IntPtr NextNode;
}
```

You could use the [fixed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f58wzh21.aspx) statement to prevent the GC to move pointers around.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question? He's asking in what situations would you do this, not what alternatives there are.

Comment: Ok, then let's answer the question: never use this construction.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't what I'm asking. I know there are other ways to do this (first one won't work for me though), just want to know if this could even work at all.

Comment: Oh come on, you haven't defined what do you mean by `work`. It will compile, yes, but in what context are you using this?

Comment: Well, in the original question, I didn't ask if it *worked*, I asked if it was safe. That was the question. FYI, I'm implementing a tree structure that is stored in a 1D array. The tree is traversed (in the original C code) by incrementing a pointer, and where each node contains a pointer to the next node, its sibling. The same thing could be accomplished by incrementing an array index and storing an array index to the next sibling, I know that. That wasn't the point.

Comment: The first version is simply broken and won't compile, because it's trying to define a recursive `struct`. The second version gives nothing over a proper pointer type - it lets one omit `unsafe`, but you'll need pointer casts when you actually use the field, and _those_ will need `unsafe`. So what's the point?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the garbage collector can move the objects around and, no, it will not update your pointers. You need to fix the objects you point to. More information can be found on this [memory management explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664640%28VS.71%29.aspx).

You can fix objects like this:

```
  unsafe {
     fixed (byte* pPtr = object) {
         // This will fix object in the memory
        }
     }
  }
```

The advantages of pointers are usually performance and interaction with other unsafe code. There will be no out-of-bounds checks etc, speeding up your code. But just as if you were programming in e.g. C you have to be very careful of what you are doing.

Comment: Yes, but it's not fixed not long enough to be useful in a linked list.

Comment: Fixing is always done within a certain context (for example a method) and while you could do something silly like fixing it in your main method, this would cause fragmentation. So fixing would not be suitable for longterm storage.

Comment: I definitely don't see how this answers his question.

Answer (score 2):

A dangerous idea, but it may work:

When your array of structs exceeds a certain size (85000 bytes) it will be allocated on the [Large Object Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc534993.aspx) where blocks are scanned and collected but not moved...

The linked article points out the danger that a newer CLR version might move stuff on the LOH...