# System.Type class and the IsPointer property

Tags: c#, system.type

what is the major reason for  The System.Type class to hold the "IsPointer" property?

I have read that it could be used as the "Isprimitive" to check if the type is primitive or not. is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [primitive types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isprimitive%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are Boolean, Byte, SByte, Int16, UInt16, Int32, UInt32, Int64, UInt64, Char, Double, and Single.

[IsPointer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.ispointer.aspx) - indicates whether the Type is a pointer. Pointer call can be declared even in C# in *unsafe* [block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703827/c-using-pointer-types-as-fields):

```
unsafe struct Node
{
    public Node* NextNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just quoting from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.type_members%28v=VS.80%29.aspx):

> `Type.IsPointer` Property - Gets a value indicating whether the `Type` is a pointer.
>
> `Type.IsPrimitive` Property - Gets a value indicating whether the `Type` is one of the primitive types.